# Regular Expressions: Print last in group

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I wrote a script to find a certain string and print a certain occurrence. This worked very well until the groups become an indeterminate length and I simply need to print the last one. I was curious for the found2.group and found3.group if there was a way to simply only print the last result.

```
f = open ("CompTime.csv","w")
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(dir, '*.out') ):
    file_handler = open(infile, "r")
    content = file_handler.read()
    file_handler.close()
    #Find Real Time
    found2 = re.search(' REAL TIME  *.+', content)
    rtime = found2.group(0)[1:-1]
    #Find CPU Time
    found3 = re.search(' CPU TIMES  *.+', content)
    ctime = found3.group(0)[1:-1]
    #Create and Format the results.
    tResult = str(rtime)+','+str(ctime)
    f.seek(0,2) 
    f.write(tResult+'\n')
f.close()
```

Is there any way to do this simply I have read the literature on the regular expressions but I seem to be failing at completing this.

Working Version:

```
dir = os.getcwd()
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(dir, '*.out') ):
    file_handler = open(infile, "r")
    content = file_handler.read()
    file_handler.close()
    rtime = re.findall(' REAL TIME  *.+', content)[-1]
    #Find CPU Time
    ctime = re.findall(' CPU TIMES  *.+', content)[-1]
    #Create and Format the results.
    tResult = str(rtime)+','+str(ctime)
    print tResult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that re.match only looks for first occurence, you can use re.findall(pattern, string) instead:

```
>>> re.findall('-[a-zA-Z]', 'ls -A -H -B -b .')
['-A', '-H', '-B', '-b']
```

Then you can just access it like any other list:

```
>>> re.findall('-[a-zA-Z]', 'ls -A -H -B -b .')[-1]
'-b'
```

Comment: More concise way of doing things. I added an updated version to the original post.